# Fixing the "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer" error

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using a Windows 10 system and I installed Eclipse, I have run java projects through cmd but I needed an IDE, every single time that I try to run a class file I get this error message:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module myproject not found

or something similar.

This is the code I'm running:

```
package myproject;                                                                              

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: In case you renamed the module in `module-info.java`, delete the existing run configuration in _Run > Run Configurations..._ and try again. Otherwise, tell if the Java file is in a source folder of a Java project and if errors are displayed, and if so, which.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Java is running properly  then you will understand the problem is on JDK or on eclipse.

1. Deleted all projects from eclipse, not from the computer.
2. Create a new project and as soon as you give the name of your project, you get another window, in which is stated as: "Create module-info.java". Select "don't create"
3. Created a package and a Java class inside the package and I run the file normally and it was working fine.